# Dealing with natural break points in timeseries

Tags: time-series, feature-engineering

Assume I have date-related data with some periodicity such as used for weather or sales forecasts. From this data I extract features such as calenderweek and keep those numerical, since week 2 is close to week 1 and 3. How ever this relation breaks as the year changes (week 52 => week 1).

Are there any tricks or transformations to avoid this break and still keep dimensionality at one?

Answer (score 1):

Use daily data . Holiday effects , long-weekend effects , day-of-the-month , week-of-the month etc can all be identified along with pulses/level shifts/time trends . You can then roll up your forecasts to whatever level you like. See https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A3382+daily for more discussions on daily data/